# How do I extract degrees / education and year from a resume? in python using NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have tried this below code but unable to extract correct education and year from a resume.

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# load pre-trained model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# Grad all general stop words
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# Education Degrees
EDUCATION = [
            'BE','B.E.', 'B.E', 'BS', 'B.S','C.A.','c.a.','B.Com','B. Com','M. Com', 'M.Com','M. Com .',
            'ME', 'M.E', 'M.E.', 'MS', 'M.S',
            'BTECH', 'B.TECH', 'M.TECH', 'MTECH',
            'PHD', 'phd', 'ph.d', 'Ph.D.','MBA','mba','graduate', 'post-graduate','5 year integrated masters','masters',
            'SSC', 'HSC', 'CBSE', 'ICSE', 'X', 'XII'
        ]

def extract_education(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)
    # Sentence Tokenizer
    nlp_text = [sent.string.strip() for sent in nlp_text.sents]
    edu = {}
    # Extract education degree
    for index, text in enumerate(nlp_text):
        #print(index, text), print('-'*50)
        for tex in text.split():
            # Replace all special symbols
            tex = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!|,]', r'', tex)
            print(tex)
            if tex.upper() in EDUCATION and tex not in STOPWORDS:
                edu[tex] = text + nlp_text[index + 1]
                print(edu.keys())

print(extract_education(text)) #resume parsed into text
```

Text:

```
B.Tech Computer Science  -  2016, MSc Computer Science - 2018 and other text...... (focusing on degree part of resume)
```

Output for the above is not showing anything .. --

```
[]    #empty list
```

Desired output:

```
[[B.Tech, 2016], [MSc, 2018]]
```

Can someone help me to correct this code and fetch passing year of that respective education?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please attach your run results. Some examples like what you're expecting and what output you got.

Comment: @Mandy8055: Please recheck the question, and added present output and expected output,  sample text too.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/GmTFCL/3) help? [Python Implementation](https://onlinegdb.com/SJjhGxr2U)

Comment: Not really....regex will not help as far I know. Coz if I parse other resume, then it will not fetch it. So how can we generalise and get the desired output.

Comment: I need the exact same, you got the answer I need that

Answer (score 0):

Change string to text:

```
[sent.text.strip() for sent in nlp_text.sents]
```

Add `return list(edu.keys())` in last to return the list of degrees.

This will give you degree name like ME, CBSE